# Confusion about dynamic binding

Tags: java

As I learned from a text book, if I assign a variable name of type superclass, saying `newObject`, to an object of type subclass, and the subclass has some overridden method, saying method `toString()`, then when I call `newObject.toString()`, the overridden method is called, not the original method.

But in another situation, I did not this happened again. For example, my superclass named `Ship`, whose subclass `CruiseShip`.

```
class Ship{}

class CruiseShip extends Ship implements Serializable {
    int getSize() {
        return 42;// value is not important now
    }
}
```

I serialize instance of `CruiseShip` and then de-serialize it.

```
CruiseShip cs = new CruiseShip();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
oos.writeObject(cs);
oos.close();

ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(
        baos.toByteArray()));
Object obj = ois.readObject();
ois.close();
```

Now the return object is of type `Object`, so I type cast into type `Ship`, so that I can assign it to a variable name `newShip`, whose type is `Ship`.

```
Ship newShip = (Ship)obj;
```

The problem is I cannot call some method of the class `CuiseShip`, saying `getSize()`,

```
int size = newShip.getSize();//error: method getSize() is undefined for the type Ship
```

which is not defined in the superclass `Ship`. Only when I type cast the object into `CruiseShip`, I can call the method.

```
int size = ((CruiseShip)newShip).getSize();//OK
```

So, what happens here? I expected that dynamic binding would allow me to use the `newShip` to call the method `getSize()`, but it did not.

Comment: Don't describe your code but post actual code examples reproducing problem/question which you want to solve.

Comment: it is not the code, but the concept that matters here. As I said, I type cast and no trouble. But I cannot explain why dynamic binding did not apply here.

Comment: I get what you want to ask, but to make your question easier and more readable for future readers it is better to include code examples instead of only code description.

Comment: gotcha. I will update my post.

Comment: Parent class don't know about it's child individual methods. That's it.

Comment: I added some code example. Hope it illustrates your problem correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not quite how dynamic binding works. If the method exist in the *superclass* and is overridden in the *subclass* then even when called on an object of declared type *superclass*, if it is actually of type *subclass* than the method of *subclass* will be called. However, if the method is not defined in the *superclass* than it can not be called from an object declared to be of that type. It wouldn't make sense otherwise - What if the object was not of type *subclass* but only of type *superclass* - It would be a type error.

If you can't implement the method in the superclass than you are either not doing an example for which dynamic binding is appropriate or your superclass should actually be an interface or abstract.

For example:

```
class Animal
{
    void Eat(){
        System.out.println("Yum!");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal
{
    void Eat(){
        System.out.println("Arf!");
    }
}
```

Now, if you write

```
Animal rex = new Dog();
rex.Eat();
```

the output will be "Arf!"

however, if you change `class Dog` to be

```
class Dog extends Animal
{
    void Eat(){
        System.out.println("Arf!");
    }

    void Bark(){
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}
```

and write

```
Animal rex = new Dog();
rex.Bark();
```

you will receive an error - Animal's can't bark. And in fact if rex had been a Fish, It really wouldn't have made sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is expected behaviour.

The parents - for example Ship - does not know anything about their children. You can have thousands of different classes which are childs of Ship.

Comment: So how do you explain about the first situation?

Comment: Ancestor of class newObject is Object. Object has method called toString(), therefore it is accessible even in newObject.